# load average too high

Tags: ubuntu, zimbra

As I can know where the problem of overload?

```
top - 13:14:12 up 2 days, 20:07,  4 users,  load average: 39.30, 38.39, 35.45
Tasks: 1637 total,   1 running, 1636 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8064172k total,  7670360k used,   393812k free,   241264k buffers
Swap:  4075516k total,        0k used,  4075516k free,  2856200k cached

memory         7875MiB System memory
processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
SO             Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64
kernel         3.2.0-32-generic x86_64

//settings
vm.swappiness   0
```

i only have zimbra 8.0.0 installed about 225 mailbox acounts, an average of 40 online accounts.

Comment: try apt-get install htop to see it by each process and see if that helps. Example of htop: http://htop.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=screenshots

Comment: I launch any application waits. I must do it with basic commands